# Why do you set number of cells when trying to implement OpenMPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmpi

I am trying to learn how to use OpenMPI and came across this example code

```
#include "mpi.h”
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Call MPI initialization
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  // Get my processor ID and number of processor
  int myProcID;
  int numProcs;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myProcID);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);

  // Set number of cells from command line argument
  int numCells  = atoi(argv[1]);

 <etc…>

  // Find which piece of the integral this 
  // processor is responsible for
  int numCellsPerProc = numCells/numProcs;
  int myStart = myProcID * numCellsPerProc;
  int myEnd   = myStart + numCellsPerProc;

  // Account for unequal load by making sure 
  // last processor has correct end
  if (myProcID == numProcs - 1) myEnd = numCells;
  // Loop over cells and compute integral 
  // using trapezoidal rule
  double myResult = 0.0;
  for (int i = myStart; i < myEnd; ++i)
  {
    double xL = xMin + i*dx;
    double xR = xL + dx;
    myResult += 0.5 * (myFunction(xL)+myFunction(xR)) * dx;
  }

  // Sum result across processors
  double totalResult;
  MPI_Reduce(&myResult, &totalResult, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM,
             0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  // Print the result, but only from root processor
  if (myProcID == 0)
  {
    std::cout << "result = ";
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10)
              << totalResult << std::endl;
  }

  // Call MPI_Finalize
  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}

<etc>
```

Forgive my ignorance when it comes to the actual architecture of a processor. Why is the example code setting the number of cells ? I thought each processors as a whole is responsible for a single job at a time?
I do not understand these lines at all...

```
  // Set number of cells from command line argument
  int numCells  = atoi(argv[1]);

 <etc…>

  // Find which piece of the integral this 
  // processor is responsible for
  int numCellsPerProc = numCells/numProcs;
  int myStart = myProcID * numCellsPerProc;
  int myEnd   = myStart + numCellsPerProc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on command line argument -- the `argv[1]` -- how many jobs you will have per node ( e.g. in OpenMPI, you can specify, via `-N`, the number of jobs per node ). Additionally, you can spawn threads to make use of multicore processors.

Actually, you are computing the integral
 [image: \int_0^cell myFunction(x) \mathrm{d}x].
You split the integration interval [image: [0,cell]] into `numProcs` parts, so each job computes his part, and in the end, all is summed up by the reduction.

( a word `cell` - is not a good variable name in this context )